# Internal Server error on the first request (and *only* the first request) after server reload

Tags: django, virtualenv

Each time I do a server reload after updating my Django app (running on httpd, using mod-wsgi), the first request is always an internal error.

The problem is always the same -- the app can't import a given model from another app. Unfortunately `ImportError` is maybe the least helpful of all exceptions in that it doesn't tell you why an import failed, only that it did.

Has anyone encountered this problem, and how was it resolved? Right now there is no workaround, since there are `models.py` files that rely on this other model. Normally I would assume there was an error in the code, but as the request works every other time I'm guessing it's running into problems for some other reason.

Details:

- Django 1.3
- running under virtualenv
- app that is being imported is not part of main project but included via `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just give a shot to importing that models module in the manage.py script to see if a preload will work. Also keep an eye out for circular imports (modules importing one another).

Comment: If it were a circular import, I'd get an Internal Server error on every request, not just the first one. Not sure how putting it in the manage.py script would help.

Comment: No, certain import order issues will rectify themselves and so will only occur on first request. So is incorrect to believe that will get Internal Server Error on every request.