# Field available via Django shell but not via web application

Tags: django, django-queryset

On the web page, I get the following error:

```
FieldError at /foo/bar/
Cannot resolve keyword 'foos' into field. Choices are: __unused__, [snip]
```

The problem code is

```
User.objects.filter(foos__name='bar')
```

When I run this in the shell, it works and I get a recordset:

```
>>> User.objects.filter(foos__name='bar')
[<User: JordanReiter>]
```

But on the webpage I get the exception above.

I've never run into this issue before and I wonder if I'm missing something?

## Update

Based on doing a diff between the "Choices are: ..." on the web and in the shell it appears there are 7 fields that are available in the shell that aren't available if I do the query on the web. They appear to be ordinary `ForeignKey` fields pointing to User, with no difference from the other fields that work.

## Tested So Far

- `INSTALLED_APPS` are identical for both settings
- `runserver` version also works (as would be expected)
- `User` used is identical in both cases and is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`
- related names for the shell's User and the web app's User are **definitely** different. `User._meta.get_all_related_objects()` in the shell displays around 7 more related fields than the if I dump that from the web app.
- values for settings are also basically identical (one has the `TEST_XYZ` settings but those don't affect anything)

Comment: "User.object.filter" Is this code correct, or there's a missing 's'?

Comment: Longshot; have you imported a different user (ie. not the contrib.auth.models.User) in your code?

Comment: Is the web server using the same `settings.py` as your shell? If the reverse FK relationship to the `Foo` model has not been created, then maybe the app that contains the Foo model is not being loaded by the webserver.

Comment: Yes, the are using the same settings.py file.

Comment: Sounds like you made changes to your models after running syncdb. The `syncdb` management command will *not* make changes to any existing tables; it will only add new tables. If you need to make changes to models after the site goes live, you should be using something like South to do migrations.

Comment: Addition to Chris Pratt: I use 'rebuilddb' script that drops the db, syncs it again and loads fixtures.

Comment: I always thought if the problem was a `syncdb` problem, then the error would be a SQL error instead of a `FieldError`.

Comment: Also, if it were a syncdb problem, why does it work in the shell, using the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only sort-of an answer. Turns out the reason that the field is not available is because all of the installed apps' models do not correctly load in when the app is first compiled, so the app permanently believes certain fields don't exist, even after they recognize the models for those fields do exist. It appears to be related to this earlier, equally confusing problem:

[SO: Internal Server error on the first request (and *only* the first request) after server reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678452/internal-server-error-on-the-first-request-and-only-the-first-request-after)

Oh, and so how I fixed it was to change areas of code that imported the models that the web server couldn't find on the first request. Somehow, omitting those meant that the server would recognize that the fields in question were present. Super weirdness!

Comment: Wow. After several days of severe frustration, you led me on the right track.  Thanks so much for taking the time to document this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Reverse foreign keys are only added to models if the app they are in is in INSTALLED_APPS. I know you say that your settings.py is the same as in development, but somehow it is the case that your `foo` app is in INSTALLED_APPS locally, but not on the server. Do you have a local_settings override perhaps?

Comment: Nope and INSTALLED_APPS are identical. I'll add that info to the question.